# Получить доступ к ImageView элемента RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть список `RecyclerView`, в который выводятся `ImageView`. Нужно из `MainActivity` управлять `ImageView`, а именно в методе `onActivityResult` установить фон `ImageView`. Как это сделать?

Мой Адаптер

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,List<String> list){
        mDataSet = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView img1;
        public ImageView img2;
        public ImageView img3;

        public ListViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            img2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img2);
            img3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img3);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.step_item,parent,false);
        ListViewHolder vh = new ListViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private RecyclerView itemList;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ***

        itemList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
        itemList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        final List<String> itemsList = new ArrayList();

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,itemsList);

        itemList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

step_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/stepBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вам нужна ссылка на итем в списке или его позиция. Можно больше инфы про взаимодействие? Вы кликаете на элемент списка потом открываете что-то в новом окне и по результату меняете или нет фон?

Comment: Вообще хочу сделать так: Вот есть элемент recyclerview с imageview. Кликнув в imageview будет открываться галерея или камера и пользователь выберет картинку. Эту картинку потом нужно сделать фоном imageview. Ну и получить также эту картинку в File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо повесить слушатель на каждый айтем отлавливать клик и запоминать этот айтем (например в какую-то переменную). Когда отрабатывает onActivityResult - вы меняете фон (ссылка на этот айтем у вас есть), потом обнуляете переменную в том же onActivityResult item = null

Набросал пример "в лоб"

Первое в step_item можно убрать один уровень вложенности

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/stepBlock"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Активити

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener<ImageView> {


private RecyclerView itemList;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private View currentView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    itemList = findViewById(R.id.itemList);

    initList();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    currentView = view;
    //Start - startActivityForResult();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (currentView != null) {
        //Изменяете фон ( если надо) у currentView
    }
    currentView = null;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(ImageView item) {
    //Do nothing
}

private void initList() {
    itemList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("ds");
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list, this);
    itemList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

Адаптер

```
package com.hssoft.countriesgraphql.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.hssoft.countriesgraphql.R;
import com.hssoft.countriesgraphql.utils.OnItemClickListener;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mDataSet;
private OnItemClickListener<ImageView> callback;


public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mDataSet, OnItemClickListener<ImageView> callback) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.step_item, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(v, callback);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private OnItemClickListener<ImageView> callback;
    public ImageView img1;
    public ImageView img2;
    public ImageView img3;

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener<ImageView> callback) {
        super(itemView);
        this.callback = callback;
        img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
        img3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img3);
        img1.setOnClickListener(view -> this.callback.onClick(view));
        img2.setOnClickListener(view -> this.callback.onClick(view));
        img3.setOnClickListener(view -> this.callback.onClick(view));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: С Котлин пока не сталкивалась. Я в свой вопрос добавила адаптер и код активити. Вот теперь можете пояснить следующее: Есть первый элемент RecyclerView с ImageView img1, img2, img3. Пользователь нажмет на img1 выберет картинку и она установится фоном для img1, и получим File, для дальнейшей работы с этим файлом. Затем нажмет на img2 тоже выберет картинку и тоже установится фоном и тоже получим File и для 3-го также. В мой существующий код что нужно сейчас добавить, чтобы это работало

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна добавьте в вопрос R.layout.step_item

Comment: Добавила в вопрос.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна изменил ответ

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее описать код в адаптере? А точнее что делает слушатель? И что содержит интерфейс OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать интерфейс слушатель.
Передать его в конструктор адаптера и в метод bind ViewHolder-a. И вызывать его из onActivityResult. Подробнее как передать слушатель в адаптер здесь. https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: вешать слушатель надо не в bindViewHolder - т.к. он отрабатывает при малейшем сдвиге списка и кучу раз. Вешать надо в  CreateViewHolder. Да и вопрос был о другом